# Выведите текст страницы, если получен статус 200, и ошибку, если получен статус 404?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
let div = document.querySelector('div');
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetch('/ajax.html').then(response => {
        console.log(response.status); // например, 200
    });
});
```

Выведите текст страницы, если получен статус 200, и ошибку, если получен статус 404. Как это можносделать при данном коде?

Comment: `response.status` у вас уже есть) как вариант, можно воспользоваться банальным `if` .. + https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject

Comment: Благодарю Вас.!